# PayPal IPN notification missing/renamed parameters

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

In rare cases I'm getting IPN notifications with the parameters renamed. For example, rather receiving a message containing the expected parameter:

```
option_name1=<my value here>
```

instead I receive  a message with:

```
option_name1_1=<my value here>
```

And quite obviously my code does not look for a parameter with the extra _1 on the end.

Why does this happen and can I get PayPal to retry the IPN notification with the correct parameter name?

Thanks!

Comment: This happens with a transaction of type `cart`, where there can be more than one line item. Your code has to cope with this.

Comment: You need to enter there ``option_name_1=<my value here>
``

Comment: @AjeetKumar Rubbish. At least read the [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/) if you don't understand the question.

Comment: @EJP thanks for your comment. It's not possible to add more than one item in my integration and check-out process. Any other ideas?

Comment: @EJP mind you - I'm also getting option_selection1_1, mc_gross_1 as well as the option_name1_1 so it seems PayPal is acting like I've posted them a transaction where there is more than one item in the basket...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @EJP - looks like PayPal is mistakenly treating the transaction like it is a shopping cart with multiple items.

I've added checks in my IPN handler code to deal with the extra fields with the _1 appended to them (even though I'd never expect them to be there).